# updateOrCreate is not updating new created columns values

Tags: mysql, laravel

I added two new **Columns**(relationship and guardian_no) to an existing **table**. Table already has **100+ records**. I also have **Edit** interface where I can edit existing records. In **edit** form I also have fields for these **new columns**. Now I want to **update** these newly added **columns** for all 100+ records using **Edit Form** one by one. But **updateOrCreate** function only update old columns it is not updating new columns.

I am updating new columns in this way.

```
  $user_detail->relationship = $request['relationship'];
  $user_detail->guardian_no = $request['guardian_no'];
  return response()->json($user_detail);
```

When I return the model after assigning the above values. they are printing correctly, values are there but when I update the model in this way.

```
$ud= UserDetail::updateOrCreate([
          'user_id' => $user->id,
           ], $user_detail->attributesToArray());
     return response()->json($ud);
```

**relationship** and **guardian_no** are null now. Other values are updating correctly. Am i doing it wrong or missing a step?

Comment: Did you add the new columns to the Model $fillable[]

Comment: ops. i did't add new columns to fillable array in my model. Thanks man You saved my life. i spent almost 2 hours figuring out the problem.

Comment: Accept then :) No worries

Comment: It's actually better to accept it as the valid answer, welcome to Stackoverflow

Comment: Why -1? i searched a lot SO and Laravel documentation, but i did't find anything.

Comment: The negative monster attacked, it is a valid question don't worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add new fields in the table to the $fillable array.

Comment: Love the -1 without explanation

Answer (score -1):

you must add the new columns to the fillable array which you can find it on the model